# How to Set monogram to textview -- android

Tags: android, performance

How to set monogram to textview. I have only aware to fetch font to the textview, but how to set monogram to particular textview. Can anyone guide me on this topic.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to set image as monogram? Please make ques make more understable

Comment: Noo, i want to set edit text to monogram..

Comment: Please explain your question more briefly.

Comment: I want to display my textview with specific monograms. like emily or traditional monogram etc.